# How to call the function of the component from the promise in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement the below code in angular and facing some errors while executing it

```
supervisor:any = {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.supervisor = new this.proctor.nativeWindow.Supervisor({
            url: 'https://supervisor.app'
    })
}

  callFunction() {

    this.supervisor.init({
      // to indicate that data is transmitted in the format of a JWT
      provider: 'jwt',
      // get string with JWT token from your server
      // your server side must have the appropriate API implemented
      token: fetch('/api/v1/proctoring-token/'+this.attempt_id).then(function(response) {
        // console.log(response)
        if (response.ok) return response.text();
        else throw Error('Failed to get JWT');
      })
    }).then(function() {
      // start proctoring session immediately after initialization
      return this.supervisor.start();
    }).then(function() {
      
      this.execute()
      // start testing in the e-learning system here
    }).catch(function(err) {
      // in case of an error, display the appropriate message
      alert(err.toString());
      // redirect to home page,
      // to prevent the test from starting without proctoring
      location.href = '/';
    });
  }


execute() {
    //Code goes here.
}
```

I see the following error:
[image]

and the function call of `execute()` is not working from `then`

Can anyone help me how to resolve both problems?

Thanks..

Comment: Is supervisor.init return a promise? Or an Observable?

Comment: @vicnoob it returns a promise

Comment: You’re not using arrow functions in your callbacks. “This” is not what you think it is.

Comment: @MikeOne how can i fix it?

Comment: Replace all callback functions with ()=> {}

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the method `ngOninit()` to `ngOnInit()` (capitalized "i" in "Init").

Comment: Sorry about that, the `onInit`  was written correctly in the code. I have overlooked it while typing here